# How to output HTML unicode characters from an expression

Tags: angularjs

I am triying to output simples html unicode characters, for example `&clubs;` from an expression.

I have tried to use `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` but i can't make it appear in my HTML.

`$scope.character = '&clubs;';`

`<span ng-bind-html="{{character}}"></span>`

1. The html code is not injected into the span balise
2. The html code is not interpreted (the html character doesn't appear in my console, but if i don't use an expression from a controller and directly call `<span ng-bind-html="&clubs;"></span>`, i can see the HTML character correctly interpreted in my console, but still not injected into the span balise)

How to output html characters from an expression ?

I import the script `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-sanitize.min.js` and add the `ngSanitize` dependency in my app.

Comment: Why not simply use the unicode escape sequence: '\u2663'?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will have to use [$sce (Strict Contextual Escaping)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce), ngHtmlBindUnsafe was removed in 1.2

```
function myCtrl($scope,$sce){
    $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml('&clubs;');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/uPw2U/

Furthernore, you can create a filter so that you will not need to escape everything in the controller.

```
.filter('html',function($sce){
    return function(input){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-bind-html="'&clubs;'|html"></span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/uPw2U/1/