# Race condition on AngularJS $scope

Tags: json, angularjs

My site uses Angular's client-side routing. A requirement of the project is that all the body text for the site be served from a flat json file. For most of the site this is not a problem. The main index file hits the IndexController and fetches the file in the following way:

```
TextFactory.get.query(function (response) {
    $scope.textDump= response;
});
```

This gets the site's text on initial page load and then as the browser gets routed around the site it doesn't have to make the $request call ever again to continue using the text. On one of the pages (privacy policy) there is an expectation to be able to insert html formatting directly in the json file. To support this I'm doing the following the terms of service controller:

```
app.controller('TermsOfServiceController', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.$watch("textDump.tos", function (new_val, old_val) {
       if (angular.isDefined(new_val)) {
          $scope.pageContent = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.textDump.tos);
       }
    });
}]);
```

I had to do this because there was a race condition where textDump.tos had not yet received the json file from the CDN by the time the TermsOfServiceController tried to use it. This works but are there any caveats to this approach that I should be aware of? Is there a better way to achieve the same result? Thanks.

Comment: You can use something like the filter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21098541/1873485) and then let Angular's two-way binding handle the rest.

Comment: That's an awesome solution! Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output HTML unicode characters from an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097513/how-to-output-html-unicode-characters-from-an-expression)