# Angularjs JSON Unicode Characters

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, unicode

I have a JSON file generated via php:

```
$JsonObjItems = json_encode($arrObjItems, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$objFile = new \File('test.json', true);
$objFile->write($JsonObjItems);
$objFile->close();
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "raw": {
            "id": "2",
            "pid": "0",
            "sorting": "0",
            "tstamp": "1433706234",
            "Alias": "-2",
            "Menu1": "Test &#40;A,C,F&#41;\nTest1, Gr\u00fcn",
            "Menu2": "Test1",
            "From": "1433714400",
            "To": "1434060000",
            "Published": "1"
        },
        "text": {
            "Alias": "-2",
            "Menu1": "Test &#40;A,C,F&#41;\nTest1, Gr\u00fcn",
            "Menu2": "Test1",
            "From": "08.06.2015",
            "To": "12.06.2015",
            "Published": "1"
        },...
```

I'm parsing that within an angularjs/ionic app:

```
.controller('GetJson', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("test.json")
        .success(function (data) {
        $scope.all = data;    
        $scope.menu1 = data[0].text.Menu1;  
    });   
})
```

And put it out here:

```
<ion-view view-title="test" ng-controller="GetJson">
<ion-content class="padding">
    {{menu1}}
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

That generates this output:

```
Test &#40;A,C,F&#41;\nTest1, Gr\u00fcn
```

What I want is:

```
Test (A,C,F)
Test1, 
Grün
```

How can I do that?
Within the javascript json encode or within the php generating the json?
I tried that stuff in the php but I didn't got it working:

```
$JsonObjItems = json_encode($arrObjItems, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

---

**EDIT:**

With the "$sce.trustAsHtml" Filter it works here: https://jsfiddle.net/uPw2U/163/
But not with expressions:
https://jsfiddle.net/gstcppgt/3/

In both cases the \n line break is ignored, do I have to use nl2br() somehow?
I tried it here: without the expressions it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/uPw2U/170/

With expressions it doesn't:
https://jsfiddle.net/gstcppgt/11/

Whats wrong with the {{ }} stuff?

Comment: This is link for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097513/how-to-output-html-unicode-characters-from-an-expression

Comment: $scope.menu1 = $sce.trustAsHtml(data[0].text.Menu1); solve the problem with "grün" but the () still don't work: Test &#40;A,C,F&#41; Test1, Grün

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uPw2U/163/  In this it () is working.just

Comment: I tried it with your filter and using: {{menu1 | html}} it still doens't output the ( ) like it should :/ any ideas were the problem could be?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gstcppgt/3/ check this out, that's like it is in my app. where is the mistake?

Comment: ng-bind html directive is used in my fiddle and your fiddle doesnot have it  so

Comment: you have to use it  as `<span ng-bind-html="html|html">` not `{{html | html}}`

Comment: Why doesn't it work with expressions? {{}}

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml read it and vote up my comment if helped you

Comment: ok I get it, but is there no way to make the {{}} resolve with ng-bind-html ?

Answer (score 3):

if the variable has html content you need to use **$sce.trustAsHTML** instead of expression.

for line breaks you can use **style="white-space: pre;"**

Comment: Yes I know, see the discussion above. It works like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uPw2U/182/ instead of the css style I use a function nl2br. But isn't there a possibility to use the {{}} syntax with no-bind-html?